# Java : Create CDATA

Tags: java

I have a servlet and responses of this servlet are in XML format.
I have a StringBuffer containing html code. This string buffer will be located in HTTPResponse (servlet) so in XML response.

How can I parse a StringBuffer to CDATA ??

Comment: That depends entirely on how you're currently building your response XML. SAX? StAX? DOM? Marshalling? 3rd-party library? Spring MVC? --- Also, converting any text (incl. html text from a StringBuffer) into CDATA is not parsing. Parsing means to interpret the content.

Comment: @AlexK Question is about *creating* CDATA, not parsing it.

Comment: Marshalling Jaxb, the hmdl code is in attribute of à method and its this method that be marshalled

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DOM to create your XML answer, use [`document.createCDATASection(yourStringBuffer.toString())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createCDATASection%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: This assumes XML response is being built using DOM. That has not been stated.

Comment: @Andreas You're right, I've prefaced my answer to specify it is using DOM. If I find the time and OP does not edit his answer to specify the API used, I may add some other ways to solve his problem.

Comment: Yeah, let's hope my comment to the question will elicit a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If your response is just a String then the easiest way is just do.

```
String.format("<![CDATA[%s]]>", html);
```

or with string buffer

```
String.format("<![CDATA[%s]]>", stringBuffer.toString());
```